# Partition a dataframe, add columns, and replace to original dataframe- no error but poor behavior

Tags: pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment

I have a large dataset stored in pandas dataframe that I need to partitioned, perform some operations on separately (far too complex for groupby), and add multiple new columns, and return to the original dataframe now with the additional columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3,4], "B": [4, 5, 6,7]})
is_odd = np.mod(df["A"],2) == 1
df_odds = df[is_odd].copy()
df_evens = df[~is_odd].copy()

df_odds["C"] = "odds"
df_evens["C"] = "evens"
df[is_odd] = df_odds
df[~is_odd] = df_evens
```

In this block of code, I don't get an error but it doesn't behave as expected. I expect the dataframe named df to have a column "C". Why doesn't it? In my actual use case, I have many columns that I need to add after the data are partitioned into groups and would like to avoid manually adding back all the new columns.

Comment: Just `pd.concat` df_odds and df_evens to make a new df; there is no need to re-assign df_odds and df_evens back to parts of the original dataframe. `df=pd.concat([df_odds, df_evens])`

Answer (score 0):

We can use filter function and modify/create columns based on loc

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3,4], "B": [4, 5, 6,7]})
df.loc[np.mod(df["A"],2) == 1,"C"]="odds"
# here np.mod(df["A"],2) == 1 is a filter function and create or mdofify existing column using that filter
df.loc[np.mod(df["A"],2) != 1,"C"]="evens"
print(df)
```

output

```
  A  B      C
0  1  4   odds
1  2  5  evens
2  3  6   odds
3  4  7  evens
```